# What would be the time complexity of my function which removes element from linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, time-complexity

Given this struct:

```c
typedef struct LLNode {
     int info;
     struct LLNode *next;
} LLNode;
```

and this recursive function which deletes the first node in the linked list whose member variable `info` equals `x`:

```c
node* deleteNode(LLNode *pHead, int x)
{
     node *ptr;
     
     if (pHead == NULL) {
          return NULL;
     }
     else if (pHead->info == x) {
          *ptr = pHead;
          pHead = pHead->next;
          free(ptr);
     }
     else {
          pHead->next = deleteNode(pHead->next, x);
     }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is:

1. What would be the time complexity of this function, considering both the best case and the worst case?
2. What would the time complexity be if we were deleting an element of an array instead?

My answers:

1. I believe that the worst case would be that the whole list would be traversed, without finding the element `x`, which would result in O(n). Best case would be if the first node in the linked list contained `x`, and the function wouldn't need to be called again. Would this be O(1)?
2. Would the time complexity be O(n), since every element after the found element in the array would need to be moved?

I'm right? I'd appreciate a little guidance as I'm still new to these concepts. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: All your answers are correct.

Comment: You need `LLNode **phead` to actually delete the node. You just modify a local variable here and the original is unchanged. It's worth noting that recursion here is a bad fit as you'll use up a ton of stack to do what's effectively just following a chain of pointers until you hit a terminator. On long lists your program may unnecessarily crash.

Comment: Equally best case: empty list.

Comment: (2) depends on the implementation of the array. In some languages, removing the last element is O(1). In some of those languages, removing the first element is O(1). (Perl is a languages where both are O(1).)  So the worst and average cases are O(N), but the best case might be O(1).